# Too many or too few rows when using different engines when creating one table from another

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to create one table from another using

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_data ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree(/clickhouse/fedor/tables/{shard}/subfolder/new_data', '{replica}')
ORDER BY created_at
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192, allow_nullable_key=TRUE
AS
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column IS NOT NULL
```

When I use

```
ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/fedor/tables/{shard}/subfolder/new_data', '{replica}'),
```

i've got around 7-9% of expected number of rows i've got from query SELECT...FROM...WHERE

When I use

```
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/fedor/tables/{shard}/subfolder/new_data', '{replica}')
```

i've got 3 times more than expected (I assume every row occur exactly 3 times)

I would like to have exact number of rows without losses and without duplication

Answer (score 0):

`ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree` with `ORDER BY created_at`
will replace many rows with the same created_at value to one rows

How did you delete exists table data before create
`ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/fedor/tables/{shard}/subfolder/new_data'...)`?

Did you use `DROP TABLE new_data SYNC`?

Which engine do you have for `table`?

Comment: Thank you that you mentioned about replacing using ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree. After your tip, I used ORDER BY () with many variables, still got slightly another table than expected (number of rows are very close - maybe 95%).


I delete with just DROP TABLE new_data (without SYNC).


Original table has the ReplicatedMergeTree engine.

Comment: finally, i solved it with creating a new table using ReplicatedMergeTree and then INSERT INTO with SELECT statement